# Why is New Super Mario Bros. U not starting?

Tags: technical-issues, new-super-mario-bros-u

I am trying to play new Super Mario Bros. U on my Wii U and it shows the game but when I click on it, it shows a forever loop of the loading screen. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score -2):

You should try deleting the save game if it isn’t that precious and try starting the game, if it still doesn’t load. It could likely be that the Disc is damaged so look for any kind of visible scratch marks and that could be what it is.

Comment: I have deleted the file, and it did not work, and there are no scratches on the disk, thank you for trying to help me

Comment: I am thinking it is because it is old because  we  got the consle a long time ago with the game